# Django - global setting to specify all models as non-managed

Tags: django, global, meta, managed

I'm writing a Django app, but have a separate process for creating / managing the tables.  In other words, I don't want Django to manage any of the DB tables.  To accomplish this, I use `managed = False` in the `Meta` class, like:

```
class School(models.Model):

    schoolid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    schooldisplayname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

But it's annoying to have to always specify this for each model.  Is there a way to apply this as a global setting to all my models by default?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how to do exactly this. It might be better to mark them all as `managed = false` so it's explicit.

You can disable migrations globally in settings. Not quite the same...

```
from settings import *

class DisableMigrations(object):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 'notmigrations'

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this.  But I will stick with the explicit declaration, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure if a global way exists if you are looking for a quick way to mark managed=False for your existing models. You can do this.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > yourapp/models.py
```

You get managed = False in every model class by default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.